# Tera term unresponsive on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, terminal-emulator

I am unable to type data into a tera term window for a device plugged into a USB.  Information does appear when I reset and/or initially plug in the device so I know it is making the connection OK.  I just can't get the terminal to accept any inputs from my keyboard.

Comment: Some more information like what device specifically and Tera Term version, etc, might be helpful. I can tell you I use Tera Term several times per week with a USB Serial adapter and have no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the device requires communication on an additional, separate port for input to the device via a DB9 connector.